# Laravel 5.8 : manage failed mail notifications from a queue

Tags: error-handling, laravel-5.8, email-notifications

I'm a little confused about the management of mail notifications failed from a queue.

I've created a mail notification class that I use to send a same notification to multiple users.
The process works well, but i'm trying to set up a management for the notifications that would fail (like sending a mail to the admin users to alert them about the failed notifications).

Here is the mail notification class :

> ```
> class MyCustomMailNotification extends Notification implements
> ShouldQueue {
> use Queueable;
>
> /**
>  * The number of times the job may be attempted.
>  *
>  * @var int
>  */
> public $tries = 3;
>
> /**
>  * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
>  *
>  * @var int
>  */
> //public $timeout = 90;
>
> /**
>  * Create a new notification instance.
>  *
>  * @return void
>  */
> public function __construct()
> {
>     //
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get the notification's delivery channels.
>  *
>  * @param  mixed  $notifiable
>  * @return array
>  */
> public function via($notifiable)
> {
>     return ['mail'];
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get the mail representation of the notification.
>  *
>  * @param  mixed  $notifiable
>  * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
>  */
> public function toMail($notifiable)
> {
>     return (new MailMessage)
>         ->subject('My Subject')
>         ->greeting('My greeting')
>         ->line('My mail body')
>         ->salutation('My salutations');
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get the array representation of the notification.
>  *
>  * @param  mixed  $notifiable
>  * @return array
>  */
> public function toArray($notifiable)
> {
>     return [
>         //
>     ];
> }
>
> public function failed(Exception $e)
> {
>     dd('Entered failed from MyCustomMailNotification : ' . $e));
> }
>  }
> ```

I've set a listener "LogNotification" To reach the handle of notification event, with a specific instruction to generate a fail :

EventServiceProvider:

> ```
>  /**
>  * The event listener mappings for the application.
>  *
>  * @var array
>  */
> protected $listen = [
>     'Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent' => [
>         'App\Listeners\LogNotification',
>     ],
> ];
> ```

Listener:

> ```
> namespace App\Listeners;
>
> use Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationSent; use
> Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue; use
> Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
>
> class LogNotification {
> /**
>  * Create the event listener.
>  *
>  * @return void
>  */
> public function __construct()
> {
>     //
> }
>
> /**
>  * Handle the event.
>  *
>  * @param  NotificationSent  $event
>  * @return void
>  */
> public function handle(NotificationSent $event)
> {
>     $result = 1/0;
> }
>
> }
> ```

The mailing is made in a controller like this:

> ```
>     $when = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5);
>     foreach ($users as $user) {
>         $user->notify((new MyCustomMailNotification())->delay($when));
>     }
> ```

As in the failed function, I don't get any information of the notification that has failed, my question is:
**How can I related a failure with the notification that has failed?**

The goal is to be able to get the information of the user who has therefore not received his notification email.

Thanks for any help, idea or solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was so simple that I didn't see it...

As the failed function is inside the notification class, I can related to the notification simply with:

```
$this->id
```

And then of course get all the informations about the notification from model/table like user id (notifiable_id) and data field with custom informations.